# How to run tests on catkin installed packages?

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm pretty new to ROS, so my knowledge with ROS, catkin and, cmake is pretty basic. I have some questions on how should I proceed with the tests of my packages. The goal is to allow execution of each specific tests, but right now it's currently grouped (i.e, group-test-1, group-test-2, group-test-3, etc).

Here's the current setup:

- Rostest is usable only in devel mode. I need to use install mode since it's the artifact that we're going to use in production.
- I'm currently using catkin run_tests (i.e., catkin run_tests -Dgroup-test-1=on) to execute all tests for that group. I'm using options to group it, then have a foreach loop to create a test using add_rostest_gtest
- It's not possible to run --gtest-filter since it also run some scripts

So far, here's what I think are the possible solutions:

- Is it possible to use rostest in install mode? I haven't found a way to do it.
- Does it make sense if I add options in my foreach loop so that I can use it this way "catkin run_test -Dgroup-test-1-specific-test-1=on", but I'm not sure if this will work.
- ROS: Melodic
- Catkin tools: 0.6.1
- Python: 2.7.17
- Cmake: 3.10.2
- Gtest

I'm not sure if I'm in the right path. Any tips or advice will be really helpful.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/364550/how-to-run-tests-on-catkin-installed-packages?/) by [achluomalus](https://answers.ros.org/users/62377/achluomalus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2020-11-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This #q307598 says to make the tests into a normal executables outside of the rostest infrastructure, but I think you can do this install (I'll update after I get it working or not)

```
install(DIRECTORY test/ DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION}/test)
```

also

```
install(PROGRAMS
  test/my_test.py
  DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
)
```

This installs the test file into two places though, but only the BIN destination one executes, to avoid that the `.test` files could be split up from the `.py` files they are coupled with into different directories.

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2021-10-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2022-08-26**:
I marked this as an answer, as I've done simular/the same things and worked out.